# Is there an inode for a directory?

Tags: files, filesystems, partition, directory, inode

Each file has an inode. Is there an inode for every directory ? If not, how does Linux manage directories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Directories are special *files*, hence they have inodes.

You can test that with `ls`:

`ls -li`

or using `stat`:

```
stat -c '%F : %i : %n' *
```

**Example:**

```
% stat -c '%F : %i : %n' *
regular file : 670637 : bar.csv
regular file : 656301 : file.txt
directory : 729178 : foobar
```

The number in the middle is the inode number.

Comment: It's Unix(like) - Everything is a file! - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Comment: `ls -lid` maybe?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yeah..mentioned that already (just not with `-d`)..

Comment: Most filesystems do implement directories using a special file for each directory (and thus, an inode), but some don't; HFS+ puts the entire name hierarchy in one big B-tree, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.
Use `stat *directory name*` in order to obtain inode number